# How do i display 2 listviews on the same screen

Tags: android, listview

I would like to display 2 lists on the same screen with a single scroll.
If i use 2 separate listviews, they are getting their own scrollbars.

My screen should look like below with a single scroll

listName1 //textview
list1 item0
list1 item1
list1 item2
and few more

listName2 //another textview separating the first list from second
list2 item0
list2 item1
list2 item2
and few more

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sth like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you shouldn't use wrap_content when using weight. If content is more than space, it will increase its space. use wrap_content when you are totally sure that content will not be larger than space available, otherwise use 0dp.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Custom Expandable ListView and Make it Programatically As Expanded
This Will Solve Your Issue .
1)There Will Be Only Once Scroll
2) You can Put Heading also

Comment: This is a good tutorial From ANDROID hive http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/